# Rails doesn't see my sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite

I've recently changed computers (Mac with OS 10.6.7) and I'm trying to launch my RoR application. It didn't work because apparently sqlite3 was missing. I've tried updating it using

```
gem install sqlite3
```

but it doesn't work and the following error is issued:

```
Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

But the thing is, I can use the sqlite3 command on the terminal, which launches perfectly, announcing a 3.6.23.1 version. Why can't rails see it? It is indeed not installed as a gem, is that why? Suggestions on how to solve this issue? Thanks.

P.S.: I've tried doing

```
port install sqlite3
```

but it doesn't work either because:

```
Error: Cannot install sqlite3 for the arch(s) 'x86_64' because
Error: its dependency readline is only installed for the arch 'i386'
Error: and the configured universal_archs 'i386 ppc' are not sufficient.
Error: Unable to execute port: architecture mismatch
```

Answer (score 1):

Was this system upgraded from 10.5 to 10.6? That error message that you are getting when trying to run `port install sqlite3` sounds like a number of errors that I received when I had done an upgrade and not a clean install.

My guess: you need to build a new version of readline (64-bit, your current one appears to be 32-bit) and then build a new version of sqlite3. I have no idea how many other dependencies you have on readline (probably quite a few) so this could be a little bit of a lengthy process.

This really isn't my forte, but I went through a bunch of similar issues during my upgrade, as I said, and this is how I resolved most of them.

Comment: FYI, homebrew is a much better software management system than either macports or fink.

Comment: @Jeremy you make a good point. I use homebrew as well, but avoided mentioning it as to not have him necessarily go down a long road of not having a working system :P Maybe I'll update my answer shortly, as I agree that homebrew is the way to go.

Comment: Mine is a brand new Mac. Didn't upgrade it. What if I want to install only the 32 bit version, is there a way to specify that in the command line when using Mac Ports? This way I wouldn't need to build another version of readline.

Answer (score 0):

Having the sqlite gem and sqlite is not the same thing. You've got the database, but you need the gem installed to allow ruby to access your sqlite db.

The gems you should have are

```
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
```

Try installing gem `sqlite3-ruby` it should auto grab the right dependency. I've also seen that error if permissions are not correct, you may need to run the command as `sudo`.